# jQuery, ajax, and php web scraper acting strangely

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a web page, but getting some weird results in my browser's console (as seen below). Here's my code:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Icefilms Searcher</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <div id="container" style="width:1100px;position:relative;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var currNum = 168000;
var maxNum =  168005;

function generateNextUrl(){
    currNum++;
    return currNum-1;
}

scrapeThis(generateNextUrl());

function scrapeThis(theUrl){
    $.ajax({
        url:
            "php.php",
        data:
            "icefilmsURL=" + theUrl,
        success:
            function(response){
                var movieTitle = $(response).find("#videotitle").find("span:first").text();
                $("#container").append("<a href='http://www.icefilms.info/ip.php?v="+theUrl+"' target='blank'>"+movieTitle+"</a><br>");
            },
        complete:
            function(){
                if(currNum < maxNum+1){
                    scrapeThis(generateNextUrl());
                }
            },
        error:
            function(xhr,err){
                $("#container").append("readyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: "+xhr.status);
                $("#container").append("responseText: "+xhr.responseText);
            }
    });
};
});
```

**php.php**

```
<?php
    echo file_get_contents("http://www.icefilms.info/ip.php?v=".$_GET["icefilmsURL"]);
?>
```

**The code works fine, but this is what I see in my console:**

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing those in the console because the page you are scraping contains references to relative paths.

That is to say rather than

```
<img src="http://www.icefilms.info/someimage.jpg">
```

The code is

```
<img src="someimage.jpg">
```

Therefore, when you grab and display their HTML on your own domain the browser is trying to load the image from your domain, localhost in this case. But you do not have the image on your server.

You can use a base href in the HTML to resolve this, or you could find and replace relative path images to include the domain.

```
<base href="http://www.icefilms.info/">
```

Comment: OK, that's what I was thinking. I removed the errors by `preg_replace`-ing any "src" tags from `file_get_contents`. But it still doesn't make sense to me because I'm not executing / parsing any of the code, I'm just sifting through it to find text. At which point in my code is the browser deciding execute and search for images?

Comment: You output the responseText on error - possible you encountered an error?

Comment: Anyone have any feedback on this?